# Mean Percentage Ranking in implicit feedback ALS

Tags: recommender-system

What is Mean Percentage Ranking in implcit feedback recommendation systems. Why should it be less than 50%? There are vague definitions in many forums. But, no clear cut examples. Can someone explain me the concept?

My understanding:

[image]

Are the above calculations rights? Is this how you calculate MPR?

Comment: I removed some of the unrelated tags from your question.

Comment: D Aparna, please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that you are using implicit feedback recommendation systems, where you observe the number of page visits on the $i$-th items page by $u$-th user $r_{ui}$, let's define a function that tells us that the user visited the page at least once

$$d_{ui} = \begin{cases}
r_{ui} > 0 & 1 \\
r_{ui} = 0 & 0
\end{cases}$$

then you use your recommender system to make ranked predictions, where $\text{rank}_{ui} = 0\%$ is the most preferred item, and $\text{rank}_{ui} = 100\%$ is the least preferred item. To achieve this, you take any recommender system, that predicts some kind of scores $\hat r_{ui}$, you sort the observations by the scores, and assign the $1/n\times 100\%,2/n\times 100\%,\dots,n/n\times 100\%$ the ordering-based ranks to them. Then MPR is defined as

$$
\text{MPR} = \frac{\sum_{ui} d_{ui} \times \text{rank}_{ui} }{\sum_{ui} d_{ui}}
$$

so this is the *average rank given to the items that were actually visited by the user*. You want your recommender system to predict low ranks for the items that are visited by users, and high for the ones that are not visited by the users (why should you recommend something that does not interest the users?). What follows, if you scrambled the ranks uniformly at random, then for any given user-item pair, the ranks could get any value in $0\%$ to $100\%$ interval, with mean $50\%$. So your recommender *needs* to be better then assigning the ranks at random.

For more details, you can check the papers Li et al (2008) [Improving One-Class Collaborative Filtering by Incorporating Rich User Information](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.228.7135&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and Hu et al (2008) [*Collaborative Filtering for Implicit Feedback Datasets*](http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf).

Comment: "then you use your recommender system to make ranked predictions," - what does this mean? I am using spark's ALS recommender system. For each user i take top 10 recommendations based on predicted value (0-1). what is ranked prediction? How do i calculate ranked prediction? How do you tell that rankui=0% is the most preferred item, and rankui=100% is the least preferred item?

Comment: @aparna I edited for clarity

Comment: can you please take a look at this image - https://imgur.com/Lgp1EtN & tell me if i got it right?

Comment: @aparna yes, this seems correct.If you want code example in Spark MLlib, here you can find a notebook: https://gist.github.com/twolodzko/7becd98ff256ef826b56945de297700d

Comment: awesome. Thanks mate! I will take a look at the code.